# `npm publish` and then `npm install` does not recover the published package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

last week I published a really simple package on NPM. It only comprises three files:

```
package.json  README.md  tofjs-full.node.js
```

The `tofjs-full.node.js` contains the whole code, the package is called `tofjs-full` and it should be available after a `require('tofjs-full')` call.

The `package.json` file has the following content:

```
{ "name": "tofjs-full",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "`tofjs-full` is the current state of the [TofJs](http://tofjs.org) program, bundled in a single NPM package.",
  "author": "bucephalus <bucephalus.org@gmail.com> (http://bucephalus.org)",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "http://tofjs.org/program/tofjs-full",
  "bugs": { "url": "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tofjs" },
  "repository": "http://tofjs.org/package/tofjs-full/1.0.0/",
  "main": "tofjs-full.node.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "markdown": "^0.5.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "sha1-file": "^1.0.0",
    "coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
    "escodegen": "^1.8.0",
    "esprima": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "files": [ "tofjs-full.node.js" ] }
```

I published the package by going to the according directory and call

```
npm publish
```

I don't remember the precise reaction. But the package `tofjs-full` is now officially available from the NPM repository (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tofjs-full).

However, when I go to another machine and try a
  sudo npm install tofjs-full
the answer is a display with the tree of all dependencies and then some warnings (each line beginning with `npm WARN`):

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `'/path/to/dir/package.json'
No description field.
No README data.
No license field.
```

Can you tell me what's going wrong, please?
Thank you, Bucephalus

Comment: ... sorry, I meant to say "The package `tofjs-full` is now officially available from the NPM repository." instead of "... not officially available ...".

Answer (score 1):

It is just a warning as it can't find the package.json for your project, since I assume like me you just went into a directory and ran `npm install tofjs-full`. It can be safely ignored.

```
npm install tofjs-full
- rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 node_modules/node_modules/node_modules/rxjs
- zone.js@0.6.12 node_modules/node_modules/node_modules/zone.js
/path/dir
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
└─┬ tofjs-full@1.0.0
  ├── coffee-script@1.12.2
  ├─┬ escodegen@1.8.1
  │ ├── estraverse@1.9.3
  │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
  │ ├─┬ optionator@0.8.2
  │ │ ├── deep-is@0.1.3
  │ │ ├── fast-levenshtein@2.0.6
  │ │ ├── levn@0.3.0
  │ │ ├── prelude-ls@1.1.2
  │ │ ├── type-check@0.3.2
  │ │ └── wordwrap@1.0.0
  │ └─┬ source-map@0.2.0
  │   └── amdefine@1.0.1
  ├── esprima@2.7.3
  ├─┬ fs-extra@0.30.0
  │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
  │ ├── jsonfile@2.4.0
  │ ├── klaw@1.3.1
  │ ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  │ └─┬ rimraf@2.5.4
  │   └─┬ glob@7.1.1
  │     ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
  │     ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
  │     │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
  │     ├── inherits@2.0.3
  │     ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.3
  │     │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6
  │     │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.2
  │     │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
  │     └── once@1.4.0
  ├─┬ markdown@0.5.0
  │ └─┬ nopt@2.1.2
  │   └── abbrev@1.0.9
  ├─┬ sha1@1.1.1
  │ ├── charenc@0.0.2
  │ └── crypt@0.0.2
  └── sha1-file@1.0.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/dir/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/dir/node_modules/node_modules/package.json'
npm WARN @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN xxxx No description
npm WARN xxxx No repository field.
npm WARN xxxx No README data
npm WARN xxxx No license field.
```

You should find that the library was installed at `/path/dir/node_modules/tofjs-full`

Comment: Ahhh, you are great! Thank you very much for your response, I am very grateful. But the problem is, that the package does not install. It does show after a `npm ls`, indeed. But when I run a `node` session and call `require('tofjs-full')`, it says `Error: cannot find module 'tofjs-full'.

Comment: @user2527816 looking at the contents of your package I only see the following `README.md & package.json`. It seems when you did the npm publish that was not done correctly or with the correct files and or configuration.

Comment: @user2527816 I think it might have to do with your `"repository": "http://tofjs.org/package/tofjs-full/1.0.0/"` configuration. It seems that is not a valid repository.

Comment: Hi Kody, thank's a lot!! Yes, indeed, when I look into the tree of my re-installation, I also see two files, only: `package.json` and `README.md`. The `tofjs-full.node.js` is missing, indeed. Maybe, that is due to the fact, that in the directory, where I published from, this file name was only a soft link to the file `tofjs-full.node.js` at some place else. This would be a strange behavior. But it would explain the failure to me. Maybe, I should try a second patch installation with the original file.

Comment: @user2527816 Yeah a symlink would likely cause the issue. Hopefully this answer helped get you to the solution you were looking for!

Comment: Hi Kody, thank you, once again! Yes, the repository does not seem to be valid, and I somehow knew that. But this should not cause the problems as they appeared, right? The repository is not an essential information for the installation process, or is it?

Comment: @user2527816 It is useful as it is linked to on the sidebar of https://www.npmjs.com/package/tofjs-full - Having a correct repository link will help others see the code and possibly contribute!

Comment: Yes, Kody, I will try an update without a soft link next. Even if that might not bring the solution, you nice guys out there gave me hope again with this whole project. I tried the official NPM support last Friday, but I waited five days in vain. ... Anyway, thank you very very much. I really owe you!! :-)

Comment: @user2527816 No problem! Hopefully this solved the problem, if so make sure you mark the correct answer here so that others coming to this thread can identify a solution quickly!

Answer (score 0):

I published a package with three files, but one of the files was a soft link to the original file. It seems, that `npm publish` ignores soft links, because a subsequent `npm install` did not know about the file. I solved the problem by another patch, where I replaced the soft link by a proper file.
Thank you Kody and baao, you really made my day by helping me! :-)